# WPF TextBox doesn't switch to new line

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextBox`, which I want to be multiline and automatically sized to parent:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    IsEnabled="{Binding CanModify}"
    Margin="0"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding Comment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
/>
```

Most suggestions to make the `TextBlock` automatically switch to new line are about adding `TextWrapping="Wrap"`  to it's properties, to prevent it from stretching it's usually `AcceptsReturn="True"`, `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` or manually set `width`. As you see, the only thing that I haven't yet tried is width, but in my case `TextBox` should fit to container, which width is unknown (also depends on it's parent). Having properties set as in listing doesn't help: caret never moves to new line and stretches the `TextBox` and the whole window as well.

What can I do to prevent this `TextBox` from stretching and to move text to new line automatically?

**EDIT**: Container is a `TabControl`. Containing tab:

```
<TabItem Header="{some binding}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TabHeight" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TabWidth" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding CanModify}"
                 Margin="0"
                 Style="{some style}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="{Binding Comment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 />
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

This `TabControl` lies in a simple `Grid` without any specific styles of constraints. Alas, I can't share the whole code of styles, applied to `TabControl`, but I'd highly appreciate any ideas to try.

`SharedSizeGroups` you see are intended to stretch the whole `TabControl` to the widest tab, preventing it from resizing on tab switches and shared only with another tab (there are two in this `TabControl`).

Comment: It's width. You have problems with layout, e.g. all parent containers resize themselves, so nothing prevents `TextBox` width from being rised. You can bind `TextBox.MaxWidth` to some element `ActualWidth` to limit its width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent a TextBox from horizontal expanding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857270/prevent-a-textbox-from-horizontal-expanding-in-wpf)

Comment: Can you show your container where you use the `TextBox`?

Comment: @Sinatr can't agree with you. What if I had to resize window (and `Texbox` as its child) by dragging a corner but not to resize it on its own? This is actually the reason, why I don't want to set `MaxWidth` manually.

Comment: I am not asking you to set it statically, rather bind it to a width a dynamically changed container. If you resize element which `ActualWidth` is the source of binding, then binding will automatically change `MaxWidth`, thus resizing `TextBox` and re-wrapping the text according to new allowed width.

Comment: I wonder; how could I misunderstand your point. Yes, it is exactly what I need. Please, post an answer, so I could accepr it.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and multi-line will work. I don't know why, but that was the problem for me.